# analysis algorithm - recurrence equation (tower of hanoi)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I saw this recursive algorithm to solve the Tower of Hanoi in wikipedia. Could someone explain to me how I get the recurrence equation of this algorithm?

> Recursive solution
>
> - label the pegs A, B, C — these labels may move at different steps
> - let n be the total number of discs
> - number the discs from 1 (smallest, topmost) to n (largest, bottommost)
>
> To move n discs from peg A to peg C:
>
> - move n−1 discs from A to B. This leaves disc n alone on peg A
> - move disc n from A to C
> - move n−1 discs from B to C so they sit on disc n
>
> The above is a recursive algorithm, to carry out steps 1 and 3, apply the same algorithm again for n−1. The entire procedure is a finite number of steps, since at some point the algorithm will be required for n = 1. This step, moving a single disc from peg A to peg B, is trivial.

Comment: T(n) = sum of the three steps... please show some effort.

Answer (score 2):

First three steps can be done in a linear time, the second three steps are the recursive part, then, just simply write in recursive format what is written in plain text format:

```
T(n,A,C) = T(n-1,A,B) + 1 + T(n-1,B,C).
```

On the other hand, because labels are not important and T(n,A,B) = T(n,B,C)=T(n,A,C)=..., we can get rid of labels, so the equation will be ?